# How to sum the number of rows in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would like to have the number of voters per age group per party in this 
[excel sheet](http://www.timeatlas.com/wp-content/uploads/pivot_table_example1.xls) .

In SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from VOTING GROUP BY AGEGROUP GROUP BY PARTY
```

This might not be proper SQL syntax but you better get the idea what I want.

I created a pivot table and selected AGE GROUP and PARTY as rows but it is not clear how could I sum the number of voters in the cross-section of this two aspects.

There is a greek Sigma VALUES fiels right below but it is not clear how could I use that for summing up -- there is no menu on right-click.

How can count the rows per AGE GROUP per PARTY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the party as columns and AGE GROUP as rows or vice versa
If he results is not comfortable for you to read then you can make additional row to your row data which concatenate the rows "age group" and "party" together.
This formula combines cells a1 and b1 together with comma inside:

```
=A1&","&B1
```

Just drag the formula to all of the rows…
Than make a pivot table and add for the rows only the additional column you just made
I added the comma so you can split them back easily with text to columns.

Comment: Thanks, if I use PARTY as column and AGEGROUP as row than I can move any of them into the Sum (Sigma) field and it works. I was able to draw a 3d chart as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 count(Voter) over (partition by PARTY, AgeGroup) as Counter, Party, AgeGroup
FROM Voting
```